# Java Regex 8 numbers + an option decimal point for a total of 9 characters

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a TextEdit field in my Android application.  The pattern I need to match with this field is 0-8 digits and then an optional period and one decimal point. So 8 numbers + a decimal point for a total of 9 characters. The 9th digit can only be used if it follows the period.

Example test cases that should pass:
`1`
`12345678`
`12345678.9`
`12.3`
`.5`

My code is as follows,

On my EditText

```
mFrequency = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.myField)
mFrequency.addTextChangedListener(mFrequencyEditTextListener);
InputFilter[] frequencyViewInputFilters = { new DecimalDigitsInputFilter()};
        mFrequency.addTextChangedListener(mFrequencyEditTextListener);
```

In my DecimalDigitsInputFilter Class

```
public DecimalDigitsInputFilter()
   { 
      mPattern=Pattern.compile("\\d{0,8}(\\.|(\\\\.\\d))?");
   }


@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

    Matcher matcher=mPattern.matcher(dest);
    if(!matcher.matches())
        return "";
    return null;
}
```

It passes all of my test cases, but fails the following:
`123456789`
It is allowing the user to enter 9 digits, without a period before the last digit.

My previous Regex was `\\d{0,8}(\\.|(\\.\\d))?`
It allowed the user to enter `123456789` as well as `12345678.99`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try [`"(?:\\d{0,8}(?:\\.\\d)?)?"`](https://regex101.com/r/1ESOXc/1).  Or [`"^\\d{0,8}(?:\\.\\d?)?$"`](https://regex101.com/r/VdPCLn/1). Although I do not find fault with your current regex.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant Android code?

Comment: How do you match? You must use `s.matches(<regex>)` or `Pattern.compile(<regex>).matcher(s).matches()`.

Comment: `\\d{0,8}(\\.|(\\.\\d))?` matches `12345678`9 not `123456789`. You're possibly confused about characters. Both the dot and digit are characters. From your example, you want to match 8,9, or 10 characters max. It's possible you're just not adding anchors around your regex `^\\d{0,8}(\\.|(\\.\\d))?$`

Comment: I updated the question to show the rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work:

```
\d{0,8}(?:\.\d)?
```

#### Explanation

`\d{0,8}` matches between 0 and 8 digits.

`(?:\.\d)` matches a period followed by a digit.

`?` makes the previous bit optional.